# In Arkham Origins, what do I need to do to fast-travel

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I'm playing Arkham Origins on a PC. I need to get back to the Batcave for the next mission, but I seemingly can't fast-travel: the fast-travel icon in the Batcave is grayed out. What do I need to do to activate it? Do I need to be in a specific area or do a specific quest first?

Comment: You can't fast travel when inside a building.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be outside in an open area and not in the middle of an encounter (a fight), otherwise all unlocked Batwing Drop Points will be greyed out and unavailable.  I've found that you can initiate the fast travel under almost all circumstances (running, grappling, gliding, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

On pc, try restart from Esc menu. Its a bug thats occurs once in while.